# Probability of infinite cluster on this specific random geometry.

Tags: reference-request, clustering, percolation

## Context

We consider the plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$, which we split into squares of size $1$. Each square has a probability $p$ of being black and $1-p$ of being white, independently for each square. Let $F$ be the area covered by the black squares; this is a random subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For description, we say that a set $K \subset F$ is **connected** if for any pair of squares in $K$ there exists a path of touching black squares in $K$ connecting them. Obviously, $F$ is a union of separate connected components, which are called **clusters**.

It is well known (see for example *Percolation Theory for Mathematicians. Birkhauser, Basel, Boston, 1982.
Khruslov, E.Ya.*)  that there exists a threshold probability $p_c$ such that

- for $p<p_c$, $F$ is made of finite clusters (a.s.)
- for $p>p_c$, $F$ contains an infinite cluster (a.s.),

and it was proved that $p_c \approx 0.41.$ This phenomenon is known as *percolation*.

## My question

I would like to study a similar problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but a little bit different. In my case, I have a selection of spheres $B_i=B(x_i,1),\ i \in \mathbb{N}$, where the family of the sphere's center $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is made of random variables (see commentary, for example it could be a random Poisson Hardcore Point Process) valued in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and such as $B_i \cap B_j = \oslash,\  i \neq j$. The spheres $F=\cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B_i$ are colored in black and the rest $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B_i$ is colored in white.

As with the random checkerboard studied above, it is possible to define the notion of a cluster in $F$ for touching spheres, and it is possible that an infinite cluster of spheres appears.

I was wondering if there were references about an equivalent of this probability threshold ? I would especially like a reference on this topic if it exists.

(Feel free to retag this question as appropriate.)

Comment: You seem to suggest you're looking for $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset$ but I don't see any clean way of defining a uniform distribution over your probability space; certainly you can't just treat your centers as IIDs if you expect to have empty intersection...

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't want to go too far on the probability aspect yet. Actually, the centers must be thinked in the same way as a random point processes, which verifies a stationary and ergodicity hypothesis, as in the chapter "Spatial Point Processes" of the book "An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes
Volume II: General Theory and Structure
Authors: Daley, D.J., Vere-Jones, David ". Apart from these two hypothesis, one can furthermore assume a non-penetration hypothesis from the spheres, which gives me $B_i \neq B_j = \oslash$.

Comment: If you just let the disks intersect and use a Poisson process for their centers, then you're talking about [continuum percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_percolation_theory), specifically the Gilbert disk model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to go with Steven Stadnicki's comment and say that your distribution for the point process has to be very weird for the spheres to be non-intersecting, yet touching each other often enough to build large clusters.
I do not know if this is helpful in your setting, but maybe you should look into percolation theory on more general geometries,
for instance on [isoradial graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.2955.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and the article about isoradial graphs. You're right I believe it'll be hard to find a point process such that the probability of two ball touching be non-zero.